# Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have seen this post dotted around on the site, but the answer always appears to be the same "Remove apply plugin android-apt" but i have never and will never (because it's deprecated) use android-apt in my project? I've not included it anywhere nor applied it as a plugin in any files.

Is it possible for third party libs to add it to my gradle build file during the build process? How can i prevent this? It's causing things like ButterKnife to fail when using the new annotationProcessor

Answer (score 3):

OK, i found my own answer! It turns out the issue was my realm plugin was too old, and internally still used android-apt (Realm.io) upgrading that to the latest version (3.0.0 at time of writing) resolved the issue immediately.